# How to encrypt the redirect page link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to encrypt the page link in the redirect page..
I have written this code so that it directs all external links to the redirect page :

```
if(page_redirect != ''){$(".post-body a").each(function(){var t=window.location.origin,o=window.location.hostname,a=new RegExp("("+no_redirect+"|"+o+"|blogger.com|bp.blogspot.com|whatsapp:)");0<=this.href.match(a)&&($(this).attr("href",t+"/p/red.html?&&url=_"+$(this).attr("href")),$(this).attr("target","_blank"))});}
```

But the problem is that it shows the external link without encryption ... as follows :

**https://www.example.com/p/red.html?&&url=_https://www.ex-red.com**

I want to encrypt the link after "**_**"

eg:
**https://www.example.com/p/red.html?&&url=_h/t/t/ps/://w/w.w///./ex-$/re/d/.///com/**

I apologize, I am still weak in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to encrypt URL's:

```
window.location.href = encodeURIComponent(https://www.ex-red.com);

//Output: https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ex-red.com
```